# UiPath - How to change back from Delegate: Body?

Tags: uipath, uipath-studio

I am not aware that I changed (not even saved it differently) anything in the workflow, but the content of all containers changed to "Delegate: Body" (see picture):

[image]

The Robot works, nevertheless it is not so confortable because also preview pictures disapear, in Selector is only the window for text and I cannot validate it.

Does anyone have an idea how to turn it back?

Edit: there is result of search for packages:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is due to the fact that the designers didn't load. It's most likely a bug. Does it happen even if you close and re-open the project?

Comment: Unfortunately, yes. It happend again this weekend. Is it possible that it happen only in Community edition?

Comment: It is still a bug. How do the rest of the activities look like? 
You can report this with logs using the Report Bug button in Studio.

Comment: This is not bug for process running. It works! But I cannot to edit and develop, because functions/packages not found.